# How return elements which have more than one entry in other columns Pandas

Tags: pandas, selection

I have this DataFrame:

```
 A      B        C        D
 User1  fake_ne  'Hello'  null
 User1  year     1987     null
 User2  fake_ne  'Hello'  null
 User2  fake_ne  'Yes'    null
 User2  fake_year 78      null
```

I would like to obtain a new Dataframe Pandas which contains all the Users in column A which have more than one entry of 'fake_ne' type in columns B with associate the C value. for instance:
DataFrame2

```
   A      B        C        D
 User2  fake_ne  'Hello'  null
 User2  fake_ne  'Yes'    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by two steps filter then  check `duplicated`

```
s=df.loc[df.B=='fake_ne']
s[s.A.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[497]: 
       A        B        C   D
2  User2  fake_ne  'Hello' NaN
3  User2  fake_ne    'Yes' NaN
```